# How do I display paragraphs in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, line, break, paragraph

Ok, so I have a database and am populating a table.  I connect and populate with no problem with $sqlCommand via a php page.

my problem is one of my fields has blocks/paragraphs of content.  I need paragraphs to show, but  nl2br() isn't work.

Here's how I populate (site.com/xtblcreate.php):

```
// Create table1 in db x for storing words
 $sqlCommand = "CREATE TABLE table1 (
           id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
           a TEXT,
           b TEXT,
           c TEXT,
           d TEXT,
   page_views INT NOT NULL default '0',
           FULLTEXT (a,b,c,d)
           ) ENGINE=MyISAM";
  $query = mysql_query($sqlCommand) or die(mysql_error());
  echo "<h3>Success creating table1 in db x</h3>";

   // Insert dummy data into the table1 in db x
   $sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO table1 (a,b,c,d) VALUES
          ('something', 'something else', 'a lot \n of info', 'quick conclusion' )";
```

What I need is " a lot of info" to be broken as like two paragraphs.

Then the query on its own php page ( site.com/x.php):

```
 $search_output .= "$count result(s) for <strong>$searchquery</strong><br />";
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $id = $row["id"];
        $a = $row["a"];
        $b = $row["b"];
        $c = $row["c"];
        $d = $row["d"];

    $search_output .= "*<br>$a- <br/><b>c: </b>$c<br /> <br /> b: $b<br />finally, d:      $d<br/>";  
echo nl2br($c);
  //output $c with paragraphs
```

***please** go easy on me as I'm new at this.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape sequences such as `\n` aren't processed when using single quotes in PHP.

If you changed your query to:

```
$sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO table1 (a,b,c,d) VALUES
      ('something', 'something else', \"a lot \n of info\", 'quick conclusion' )";
```

Then I suspect `nl2br()` will yield your desired output.

Comment: but nl2br() is used in the right area (in the query section of process and not in the table populating page)?  Also since I am using full sentences, will \" impact the processing of periods?  I'm not familiar wiht \"

Comment: nl2br is used in the right area but the data isn't inserted with any newlines because the escapes aren't turned into actual newlines.  You should read [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) before going further.

Comment: a lot to process in that page.  But according to the php manual, double quote should resolve the issue. Am I understanding properly?

Comment: Yes, because `\n` isn't turned into a newline when it is in single quotes as is shown in your post.  Putting that string in double quotes will convert the `\n` to a newline, and then it is necessary to escape the quotes like `\"string\"` because the string itself is inside double quotes.  The main parts of that page to read for now are `single quotes` and `double quotes`.

Comment: thank you so much...will have to give this a shot...how do I vote you up? lol  (just getting used to the site!)

Comment: I don't think you can upvote yet, but you can accept the answer by clicking the faint checkmark to the left of the vote area.  It will give you points for accepting.